# Combining multiple change streams in ReactFX

Tags: java, javafx, reactfx

### Question

How do you correctly combine multiple property change streams in ReactFX for use in UndoFX (or any use case)?

### Details

Here's a short explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish (full example code is [posted at GitHub](https://github.com/ubertakter/CombinedEventStreamTest)):

There is an example model that has two properties. For simplicity's sake, they are double properties

```java
public class DataModel {
    private DoubleProperty a, b;
    //...
    //with appropriate getters, setters, equals, hashcode
    //...
}
```

In the example code, there are buttons to change either one or both of the properties. I would like to undo changes to both if that's what the change is.

Per the UndoFX example, there are also change classes for each (also abbreviated here) that inherit from a base class:

```
public abstract class ChangeBase<T> implements UndoChange {
   protected final T oldValue, newValue;
   protected final DataModel model;

   protected ChangeBase(DataModel model, T oldValue, T newValue) {
      this.model = model;
      this.oldValue = oldValue;
      this.newValue = newValue;
   }

   public abstract ChangeBase<T> invert();
   public abstract void redo();

   public Optional<ChangeBase<?>> mergeWith(ChangeBase<?> other) {
      return Optional.empty();
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      return Objects.hash(this.oldValue, this.newValue);
   }      

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (this == obj) {
         return true;
      }
      if (obj == null) {
         return false;
      }
      if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
         return false;
      }
      final ChangeBase<?> other = (ChangeBase<?>) obj;
      if (!Objects.equals(this.oldValue, other.oldValue)) {
         return false;
      }
      if (!Objects.equals(this.newValue, other.newValue)) {
         return false;
      }
      if (!Objects.equals(this.model, other.model)) {
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   }
}

public class ChangeA extends ChangeBase<Double> {
   //...
   //constructors and other method implementations
   //..
   @Override
   public void redo() {
      System.out.println("ChangeA redo "+this);
      this.model.setA(this.newValue);
   }   
}

public class ChangeB extends ChangeBase<Double> {
   //...
   //constructors and other method implementations
   //...
   @Override
   public void redo() {
      System.out.println("ChangeA redo "+this);
      this.model.setB(this.newValue);
   }   
}
```

All changes implement an interface

```
public interface UndoChange {
   public void redo();
   public UndoChange invert();
   public Optional<UndoChange> mergeWith(UndoChange other);

}
```

After reading up on documentation, I started by creating an event stream for to capture changes to each property:

```
EventStream<UndoChange> changeAStream = 
    EventStreams.changesOf(model.aProperty())
              .map(c -> new ChangeA(model, (Change<Number>)c));
EventStream<UndoChange> changeBStream = 
    EventStreams.changesOf(model.bProperty())
              .map(c -> new ChangeB(model, (Change<Number>)c));
```

My first attempt was to merge the streams like so

```
EventStream<UndoChange> bothStream = EventStreams.merge(changeAStream, changeBStream);
```

What happens in this case is that if A and B properties are changed at the same time, the stream will have two changes in it, and each will undo separately instead of together. Each call to a setter puts a change in the appropriate stream, which are then emitted to `bothStream`, which then contains two separate events instead of one.

After some more reading I then tried to combine the streams and map into a separate change object:

```
 EventStream<UndoChange> bothStream = EventStreams.combine(changeAStream, changeBStream).map(ChangeBoth::new);
```

where `ChangeBoth` is defined as:

```
public class ChangeBoth implements UndoChange {

   private final ChangeA aChange;
   private final ChangeB bChange;

   public ChangeBoth(ChangeA ac, ChangeB bc) {
      this.aChange = ac;
      this.bChange = bc;
   }

   public ChangeBoth(Tuple2<UndoChange, UndoChange> tuple) {
      this.aChange = ((ChangeBoth)tuple.get1()).aChange;
      this.bChange = ((ChangeBoth)tuple.get2()).bChange;
   }

   @Override
   public UndoChange invert() {
      System.out.println("ChangeBoth invert "+this);
      return new ChangeBoth(new ChangeA(this.aChange.model, this.aChange.newValue, this.aChange.oldValue), 
                            new ChangeB(this.bChange.model, this.bChange.newValue, this.bChange.oldValue));
   }

   @Override
   public void redo() {
      System.out.println("ChangeBoth redo "+this);
      DataModel model = this.aChange.model;
      model.setA(this.aChange.newValue);
      model.setB(this.bChange.newValue);
   }

   //...
   // plus appropriate mergeWith, hashcode, equals
   //...
}
```

This results in a `IllegalStateException: Unexpected change received` being thrown. After some digging, I determined why this is happening: when the `ChangeBoth` is being undone (via `invert()` and `redo()` calls), it sets each property back to the old value. However, when it sets each property, the change is emitted back through the streams resulting in a new `ChangeBoth` being put in the stream in between setting the two properties back to old values.

### Summary

So to get back to my question: what's the correct way to do this? Is there a way to combine to change streams for two properties into one change object that doesn't cause this problem?

### Edit - Attempt 1

Per Tomas's answer, I added/changed the following code (NOTE: Code in repo has been updated):

`changeAStream` and `changeBstream` remain the same.

Instead of combining the stream, I did as Tomas suggested and created a binary operator to reduce two changes to one:

```
BinaryOperator<UndoChange> abOp = (c1, c2) -> {
   ChangeA ca = null;
   if(c1 instanceof ChangeA) {
      ca = (ChangeA)c1;
   }
   ChangeB cb = null;
   if(c2 instanceof ChangeB) {
      cb = (ChangeB)c2;
   }
   return new ChangeBoth(ca, cb);
};
```

and changed the event stream to

```
SuspendableEventStream<UndoChange> bothStream = EventStreams.merge(changeAStream, changeBStream).reducible(abOp);
```

Now the button action isn't implemented in `setonAction` but is instead handled with an event stream

```
  EventStreams.eventsOf(bothButton, ActionEvent.ACTION)
          .suspenderOf(bothStream)
          .subscribe((ActionEvent event) ->{
             System.out.println("stream action");
              model.setA(Math.random()*10.0);
              model.setB(Math.random()*10.0);                 
          });
```

This works great for combining events appropriately, but undoing still breaks for A+B changes. It works for separate A and B changes. Here's an example of two A+B changes and then an undo

```
A+B Button Action in event stream
Change in A stream
Change in B stream
A+B Button Action in event stream
Change in A stream
Change in B stream
ChangeBoth attempting merge with combinedeventstreamtest.ChangeBoth@775ec8e8... merged
undo 6.897901340713284  2.853416510829745
ChangeBoth invert combinedeventstreamtest.ChangeBoth@aae83334
ChangeA invert combinedeventstreamtest.ChangeA@32ee049a
ChangeB invert combinedeventstreamtest.ChangeB@4919dd13
ChangeBoth redo combinedeventstreamtest.ChangeBoth@b2155b1e
Change in A stream
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected change received.
Expected:
combinedeventstreamtest.ChangeBoth@b2155b1e
Received:
combinedeventstreamtest.ChangeA@2ad21e08
Change in B stream
```

### Edit - Attempt 2 - Success!!

Tomas was nice enough to point out the solution (which I should have realized). Just suspend while doing `redo()`:

```
  UndoManager<UndoChange> um = UndoManagerFactory.unlimitedHistoryUndoManager(
          bothStream, 
          c -> c.invert(), 
          c -> bothStream.suspendWhile(c::redo),
          (c1, c2) -> c1.mergeWith(c2)
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the task is to combine into one the changes that have been emitted from `bothStream` during handling a button click.

You will need a function for reducing two `UndoChange`s into one:

```
BinaryOperator<UndoChange> reduction = ???; // implement as appropriate
```

Make `bothStream` reduce changes into one while "suspended":

```
SuspendableEventStream<UndoChange> bothStream =
        EventStreams.merge(changeAStream, changeBStream).reducible(reduction);
```

Now you just need to suspend `bothStream` while processing the button click. This can be done like this:

```
EventStreams.eventsOf(bothButton, ActionEvent.ACTION) // Observe actions of bothButton ...
        .suspenderOf(bothStream)                      // but suspend bothStream ...
        .subscribe((ActionEvent event) -> {           // before handling the action.
            model.setA(Math.random()*10.0);
            model.setB(Math.random()*10.0);
        })
```

Also suspend `bothStream` when undoing/redoing the change from within the undo manager, so that *exact inverse* of the (combined) change is emitted from `bothStream` when undoing a combined change (which is necessary to make `UndoManager` happy). This can be done by wrapping the `apply` argument to `UndoManager` constructor in `bothStream.suspendWhile()`, e.g.:

```
UndoManagerFactory.unlimitedHistoryUndoManager(
        bothStream, 
        c -> c.invert(), 
        c -> bothStream.suspendWhile(c::redo)  // suspend while applying the change
)
```

Comment: This almost works but events from changeAStream and changeBStream end up in bothStream when undoing.  The creation event sequence looks okay to me press button -> Change in A -> Change in B -> reduced to ChangeBoth. The undo event sequence appears to be undo button -> invert ChangeBoth (which inverts the stored ChangeA and ChangeB) -> ChangeBoth.redo() -> Change in A stream -> Exception, expected ChangeBoth but received ChangeA. I'll update my post with code.

Comment: Ah, right. Let's suspend `bothStream` also during `redo()`: create the undo manager with `c -> bothStream.suspendWhile(c::redo)`.

Comment: Duh, I should have thought of that. Works like a champ. I'll update accordingly.